# SQL left join is not including all records from left table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a requirement to get monthly total hours worked on different tasks for each employee. For that purpose I am writing a stored procedure. But left join is not populating all record from employee table.
I know somehow the where condition is filtering out the null values but I really don't know how to overcome this problem.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetEmployeeWorkHours]
@PageSize smallint = 10,
@CurrentPage smallint = 1,
@EmployeeId varchar(1000) = null,
@StartDate datetime = null,
@EndDate datetime = null
AS

 BEGIN

if(@StartDate is null)
select @StartDate = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getDate()), 0)

if(@EndDate is null)
select @EndDate = getDate()

select   e.Id,
e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName as [Name],
sum([Minutes]/60.0) as [WorkedHours]
from Employees e
left join TaskResources tr on (e.Id = tr.EmployeeId)
inner join ResourceTaskSchedules rts on (tr.Id = rts.TaskResourceId)
inner join TaskTimeSheets tts on (rts.Id = tts.ResourceTaskScheduleId)
where
((@EmployeeId is null) or (e.Id in (select splitdata from dbo.SplitEmployeeIds(@EmployeeId, ',')))) and
cast(tts.CheckIn as date) >= @StartDate
and cast(tts.CheckIn as date) <= @EndDate
group by
e.Id
ORDER BY
 e.Id
OFFSET (@CurrentPage-1)*@PageSize ROWS
FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

END

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you use `left join` in a `from` clause, you normally continue with `left join`.  This is critical if the second table is used for any conditions.

Then, any filtering conditions on any of the left join'ed tables need to be in the `on` clauses, not the `where` clause.  So:

```
from Employees e left join
     TaskResources tr
     on e.Id = tr.EmployeeId left join
     ResourceTaskSchedules rts
     on tr.Id = rts.TaskResourceId left join
     TaskTimeSheets tts
     on rts.Id = tts.ResourceTaskScheduleId and
        cast(tts.CheckIn as date) >= @StartDate and
        cast(tts.CheckIn as date) <= @EndDate
where ((@EmployeeId is null) or 
       (e.Id in (select splitdata from dbo.SplitEmployeeIds(@EmployeeId, ','))))
```

Comment: Its is now giving me the correct results, Thank You Gordon-Linoff